# Exit trade when volume increases/decreases from when I entered the trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to exit a trade when the volume over 24h either increases/decreases (by a % or absolute value) **from when I opened the trade**, not just a generic volume decrease by 5% for example. The code I have so far exits the trade when the volume increases/decreases by an amount, but how would I alter it so that it exits the trade when it, say decreases by 5% from when I entered the trade? Below is my code so far which has absolute and % increase/decrease:

```
lower_tf = input('5', title='Lower Timeframe to Assess')        // <=== Input Time Frame and Bars (288 bars for 24hrs in 5mins time frame)
bars_in_tf = input(288, title='Bars of lower Timeframe') - 1    // <=== -1 because we count from zero in the loop
//Calculating 24hrs Volume
buying_volume(range_1) =>
    vol = float(na)
    for i = 0 to range_1 by 1
        if open[i] < close[i]
            vol := na(vol) ? volume[i] : vol + volume[i]
            vol
    vol
lower_buy_vol = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, lower_tf, buying_volume(bars_in_tf))
volbuy = volume / lower_buy_vol                 // <=== Calculating percentage change with respect to 24hrs volume
increaseEntry = volbuy >= 0.03                      // <=== Long entry if Buy Volume increases by 3% or more - Change to whaterver value you want
decreaseEntry = volBuy <= -0.05                    // <=== Long entry if Buy Volume decreases by 5% or more - Change to whaterver value you want

value = 1000000                                 // <=== Value you want the volume to increase by
increaseEntry = volume >= lower_buy_vol + value     // <=== Long entry if volume increases by stated amount
decreaseEntry = volume <= lower_buy_vol - value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a strategy script, you can create conditions like below

```
InLong = strategy.position_size > 0
InShort = strategy.position_size < 0
```

With those two variables you now know if you're in a trade (long/short)

Combining them with your conditions

```
value = 1000000                                 // <=== Value you want the volume to increase by
increaseEntry = InLong and volume >= lower_buy_vol + value     // <=== Long entry if volume increases by stated amount
decreaseEntry = InShort and volume <= lower_buy_vol - value
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I'm still a bit unsure about this. To me it doesn't look like the it would exit the trade when the volume decreases by X amount from when you entered the trade.